# How to keep 2D player within boundaries?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character

How can I keep my 2D character within the left and right walls and let the objects (such as big rocks) come from both sides? Something like in the picture below. And also they should collide only with the character and should pass through each other, something like IgnoreCollisionForce()?

Sorry, I don't have 10 points to upload image

Comment: This question is a bit broad, one question is how to keep the player within boundaries, the other one is how to spawn some objects within the specific location. Another one again is how to avoid collision between objects. I would suggest to create one question for each. But first check because there could be already answers related to those questions.

Comment: There is an official Tutorial that will teach you that and more, I suggest doing it and a couple of others to get to know the basics. https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-space-shooter

Comment: Sorry my bad, I should have asked this question first
So the thing is that I want my gameobject(rock) to follow an arc, it must follow a certain path on which it would travel, in the beginning it will not be in the game scene it should only come after the game starts and then follow that pre defined path and exit the game scene and get destroyed. But I'm just not getting how to do it, I searched alot so if you can help me I would really really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make layer walls and layer player, when selecting a wall or a player, in inspector at the toop u have drop down layers, create them and assign them, wall to walls and player to player.
Then go to project settings/physics and chose what you want to collide or not collide with each other
Also don't forget that walls and a player have colliders not marked as triggers.
Just untick as on image below. 
In this case, as u wanted, walls will ignore each other and they won't collide with each other.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot mate, really love you. Your method worked like charm